# How to stop long running disk operation in Thread or Coroutine in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-thread

Let's say we have this pseudo code in Android:

```
fun writeData(fd: File, data: Data) {
    timeout (1000) { //max running time is limited to 1000ms
        val operation = create thread/coroutine { // Thread or Coroutine
            Os.write(fd, data) // <--- let say it's blocking operation for 2 minutes
        }.start()
    }
}
```

How can I immediately stop `Thread` or `Coroutine`? When I call `operation.interrupt()` (`operation.cancel()` in the case of coroutine) `thread` or `coroutine` is waiting to be completed and running 2 minutes (all the time until `Os.write(fd, data)` is finished). I need to abort operation immediately, because it is a long disk operation (don't want to wait 2 minutes).

Comment: Do not do a single OS call that takes two minutes. Divide it into smaller chunks (e.g., 120 calls that each take one second), and call `yield()` after each chunk.

Comment: I cannot. Operation is `Os.ftruncate`. It's Android API method.